# Carousel Items not appearing in horizontal in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I trying to create a multi column bootstrap carousel, but all items are appearing in vertical, PFB my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="2000" style="border: 2px black; max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px;">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://fresh2door.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Fresh2Door-Mango-Ready-To-Eat.jpg"
                        alt="First slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://sportsvape.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mango.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://jessicainthekitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Mango-Basil-Salsa-vegan-easy-6-453x680.jpg"
                        alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://fresh2door.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Fresh2Door-Mango-Ready-To-Eat.jpg"
                            alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://sportsvape.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mango.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://jessicainthekitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Mango-Basil-Salsa-vegan-easy-6-453x680.jpg"
                            alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://fresh2door.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Fresh2Door-Mango-Ready-To-Eat.jpg"
                                alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://sportsvape.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mango.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>

        $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .carousel-item').each(function () {
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                next = next.next();
                if (!next.length) {
                    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                }

                next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            }
        });

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="2000" style="border: 2px black; max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px;">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://fresh2door.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Fresh2Door-Mango-Ready-To-Eat.jpg" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://sportsvape.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mango.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://jessicainthekitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Mango-Basil-Salsa-vegan-easy-6-453x680.jpg"
                            alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://fresh2door.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Fresh2Door-Mango-Ready-To-Eat.jpg" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://sportsvape.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mango.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://jessicainthekitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Mango-Basil-Salsa-vegan-easy-6-453x680.jpg"
                            alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://fresh2door.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Fresh2Door-Mango-Ready-To-Eat.jpg" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://sportsvape.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mango.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://jessicainthekitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Mango-Basil-Salsa-vegan-easy-6-453x680.jpg"
                            alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**If you are looking for something else, then please explain your question more clearly.**

**Edited:**
This is exactly what you want:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Our Partners</h2>
  <section class="customer-logos slider">
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h2{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

**Error:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

(Remove this script from your code, this is causing that bizarre thing in your code.)

Comment: not entirely like this, your solution offers all 3 new items to be displayed at every change, I want to display 2 old and 1 new everytime like if I've got slides 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 then at first there will be 1,2,3 and after change 2,3,4 whereas your solution from 1,2,3 turns into 4,5,6. Get my point?

Comment: You cannot do that using bootstrap crousel. Because if you use 3 images in one slide, it will always move all the images to get to the next slide.

Comment: I have edited the answer, check for the edited part. I guess this is what you want. @Kushal

Comment: your solution is giving me images in vertaical alignment, no slideshow

Comment: I'm following : https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY bt still evrything is in vertical alignment

Comment: There must be some other reason. Try what I have given you in the edited part in a new file. It will work properly

Comment: (https://nikhilthakur001.github.io/modal_show_on_ajax_call/crousel.html) check my repo. Here's the live example. I have put the above code on git. @Kushal

Comment: Yes Thanks @Nikhil, but for some bizaare reason not working on my machine

Comment: Ok after looking for every reasons, i have found the fault. @Kushal. It is happening due to that `slim.min.js` that you have included at the bottom of your page. (I have edited the answer, look at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Removing this script fixed it for me too

```
{{-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> --}}
```